# Hibernate duplicate key value violates exceptions

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I got exception: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "client_pkey"
Key (xmppid)=(xyz813@deweet/prototype1006) already exists.

My configuration is Tomcat 6.0, hibernate 3.3.1, c3pO 0.9.2 or dbcp.

I don't know how to avoid this I thought that making it `UniqueConstraint` and calling it in transaction should sole everything.

Could you tip me what am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Client createClient(String userid) {
    Client c = new Client(userid);
    currentSession().save(c);
    return c;
}
```

The client class is defined as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "xmppId" }) })
public class Client {


    @Id
    private String xmppId;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Client c = (Client) o;
        if (c.xmppId.equals(this.xmppId))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.xmppId.hashCode();
    }

    ...
}
```

It doesnt point directly to this method, but to $Proxy23.createClient but i think it is 
the only place I create and save client.

> at $Proxy23.createClient(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   pl.samsung.cs.deweet.server.RequestHandler.onAddVirtualDevice(RequestHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   pl.samsung.cs.deweet.server.RequestHandler.handleRequests(RequestHandler.java:117)
>   at
>   pl.samsung.cs.deweet.network.impl.XmppNetContext$8$1.run(XmppNetContext.java:518)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use auto generated id. That means that you will have to assign it (userId, presumably). When you call `save` it will attempt to insert it every time and you get an exception.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may use `saveOrUpdate` in place of `save`.

See this reference http://www.javabeat.net/tips/161-difference-between-hibernates-saveupdate-a.html

Comment: thanks, how can I switch to autogenerated ids? would it also solve the problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use auto generated values you will be creating new records every time where you called `save()`. You will end up with multiple records for the same user id. If it's truly what you want read here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier